# C++/Curl : How to send HTML formatted email

Tags: html, c++, email, curl

I want to send an email using using C++/curl with Visual Studio 2015, that will be html formatted looking like:

**Hello World!**

instead

```
<strong>Hello World!</strong>
```

How to format it so the client reads text as text/html not just pure text ?

The piece of code I already have (doesnt work) looks like this:

```
const wchar_t tekst[] = _T("<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html> ");
_bstr_t temp(tekst);
const char* tekst_maila = temp;

static const char *payload_text[] = {
"Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2020 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
"To: " TO "\r\n",
"From: " FROM "(Example User)\r\n",
"Cc: " CC "(Another example User)\r\n",
"Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
"rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
"Subject: SMTP TLS example message\r\n",
"\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
/* body starts here */
tekst_maila,
};
```

I have found some answers, like this:

```
A very basic HTML email is described below: 

From: Test Address <your-email_at_domain.com> 
Reply-To: Test Address <your-email_at_domain.com> 
To: libcurl development <curl-library_at_cool.haxx.se> 
Subject: Test Email 
Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2012 10:00:00 +0000 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable 
Mime-version: 1.0 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p>Hello World</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

But how to actually implement that?

Comment: May or may not be relevant, but you've got three separate string types here -- which seems unnecessary -- and you're incorrectly using the `_T()` macro.

Comment: Thanks for noticing :) Answer is: yes - I tried so many versions with strings, cstring, chars and wchar_t - this code is just a scrap i work with as an expample. Nothing to worry about anything expect how to make it actually to work!